# Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding 'UTF-8'

Tags: errors, texlive, input-encodings, texniccenter

I have document in Latex. Every compile worked without errors. But now, I reinstalled my Windows 10, and the same document not working. I didn't change anything on document and now I have these Errors in Latex file pdfx.sty [image]

on this line error: 
[image]

I'm using Tex Live and text editor TexnicCenter. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I suggest you make a copy of your document and try to reduce it so far that everything that does not have anything to do with your problem is deleted and then provide this MWE to us. This way we can help you better.